# Expand Track Playlist from D-Command

Tags: pro-tools

Is there a way to expand the playlist of a track from the D-Command?

Comment: when you say expand, you mean track height? or track view?
will be on an icon soon there is a section (right above your keyboard) with a soft-key to access playlist section. I'll give you a more specific answer when I'm there.

Answer (score 1):

ok so track height you can change by using the track size buttons on the edit section of the desk (right hand side, under the ZOOM/NAVIGATE panel).
if you are trying to change playlists, with the D-Command on Focus (not select as it will still follow the selection done with the edit selection on your window), and on the soft key section (the one with the 6 led scribble bits) it says playlist. It will put on the LED option to create playlist or to cycle through them.

If you are trying to quickly change track views, may I suggest ctrl+cmd+left/right arrows? it will include the collapsed version of playlist view.

Hope i helped!